# Protect a range with apps script takes too much time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Some context**

- I manage the translations of my web app though a google spreadsheet to which I invite translators
- There are 30 sheets, each represents a part of the app (big app).
- There are 14 columns on every sheets, 1 column / language.

**What I want to do**

As I already had twice a problem with translators editing the wrong column by mistake, I want to set [protected columns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#addeditoremailaddress) to restrict edition for each translator only to the column of his language (1 translator = 1 email address granted access to the spreadsheet).

**How I did it**

Setting it manually is a pain (repetitive task), and must be done again if a translator change. So I wrote a script for it.

How i stored the permissions :

```
var ProtectionsDefinitions = [{
  langHeader: "en",
  emails: ["toto@gmail.com"]
},{
  langHeader: "fr",
  emails: ["toto@gmail.com"]
}
...]
```

Pseudo code :

```
For every sheet:
    For every language:
        Protect the column whose header match the langHeader
```

Real code for the function that do the real work :

```
function setProtection(range, rangeDesc, emails) {
  // range = class range
  // rangeDesc = string (description for protected range)
  // emails = [toto@yopmail.com, tata@yopmail.com]

  var protection = range.protect(); // Creates an object that can protect the range from being edited except by users who have permission. 
                                    // Until the script actually changes the list of editors for the range
                                    // the permissions mirror those of the spreadsheet itself, which effectively means that the range remains unprotected.
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors()); // this takes more than 1s ! 
  protection.setDomainEdit(true);  // all users in the domain that owns the spreadsheet have permission to edit the protected range
  protection.setDescription(rangeDesc);
  if(emails.length > 0){
    // this takes more than 1s !!
    range.getSheet().getParent().addEditors(emails); //  give the users permission to edit the spreadsheet itself, required for protection.addEditors()
    protection.addEditors(emails); // give the users permission to edit the protected range
  }
}
```

**Why it's not satisfying**

- The function `setProtection` takes 2s for each range to protect
- I have 30 sheets * 14 columns = 420 ranges to protect.
- The whole execution exceeds maximum time allowed by google apps script (~6min)

I traced the lines that takes a lot of times thanks to the logging tool, see comments in the function.

**I wonder if I can do something to make it work**.

**Example spreadsheet**

- translation data has been scrubbed
- structure of the sheets are preserved, script is available in script editor.
- https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RRGSWsCz-Wyk3kxdldb6X0meYRV5xNEZKNQtLgfVv48/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply to the [Early Access Program](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/apps-script-eap) or rather than process all the sheets/columns with a single script call, split the job.

Ideas for solutions:

- Parallel processing (two question equivalent answer)

  - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25438737/1595451) to [Threading in Google App Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18155538/1595451)
  - [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28157615/1595451) to [Script runtime quota exceeded when copying files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28149817/1595451)
- Use the Continuous Batch Libray (see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40464825/1595451) to [Copy & replace/insert loads of data from CSV file located on Google Drive to SpreadSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40462050/1595451))

Related Q&A

- [What happens when I "sleep" in GAS ? (execution time limit workaround)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16886550/1595451)
- [Google Apps Script trigger quota and limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40486845/1595451)

Comment: thanks for mentioning the Early Access Program (didn't know about it) and thanks also for mentioning the trigger solution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43587255/1570104) seems to provide a minimal way to implement the trigger solution. In my use case, I think I will just split the job in 3 chunks, implementing triggers looks like an over optimisation for me, but it was very interesting to understand how that would solve my problem.